# What would be regex expression for anything between two strings?

Tags: regex

I want to extract an IP address between two strings i.e Source IP: and Source Port: and the string is like this "Source IP:192.168.1.17 Source Port:"

Comment: Between two strings... or two substrings?

Comment: `Source IP\:(.+)\sSource Port\:` would probably be the easiest Regex. If your string only contains one IP, you could also do [this](https://regex101.com/r/SljfJ4/1).

Comment: Anyways, `Source IP:(.*?)\sSource Port:` [should work](https://regex101.com/r/B3K9DR/1)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs between two substrings like  Source IP: and Source  Port:

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Source IP:(.*?)\sSource Port: is including "Source IP:" and "Source Port:" in result but i want to exclude it

Comment: You should research how to obtain matches from capturing groups.

Comment: @Zaid you need to access the capturing Groups,not the full match. Maybe tell us the programming language you're using so we can help you with this.

Comment: @BoredomOverload Im using C#

Comment: @Zaid: Although you can capture your intended text by capturing groups, but If you don't want to get into capturing groups, you can use my answer which only matches the IP you want to capture in final match.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi actuall I also have other IPs in the string and I want to extract the only IP that is between "Source IP:" and "Source Port:"

Comment: Try matching an ip in a capturing group: `Source IP:((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])) Source Port:` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ob5eQR/1/)

Comment: @Zaid: Ok in that case, let me update my answer.

Comment: @Zaid: Updated my answer to use look arounds. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match just the IP part in your string, you can use this regex, which uses lookarounds to ensure it is surrounded by your intended text.

```
(?<=Source IP:)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?=\s*Source Port:)
```

Here `\d+(?:\.\d+){3}` captures the IP address and `(?<=Source IP:)` ensures it is preceded by `Source IP:` and succeeded by `\s*Source Port:`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5l451t/2)**

Hope this is what you wanted.

**Edit:**

Ok Zaid, here is a sample C# codes,

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "Source IP:192.168.1.17 Source Port:";
    var match = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=Source IP:)\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?=\s*Source Port:)");
    Console.WriteLine("IP: " + match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

This outputs,

```
IP: 192.168.1.17
```

Let me know if still something is not working for you. And if still, please edit your post and share your code and sample strings.

Comment: @Zaid: Edited my answer to include C# code. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Im having some issues can i get you on email or something?

Comment: @Zaid: you can reach me on my Skype id pkr555 but I'll be available after around 3-4 hours as going out of home. Meanwhile you can share your problem with me.